# Wrap divs com a mesma class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quero aplicar a inserção das label com JavaScript ou jQuery.

Eu tenho este código:

```
<div class="name">...</div>
<div class="name">...</div>
<div class="name">...</div>
<div class="name">...</div>
<div class="name">...</div>
```

E gostava que ficasse assim:

```
    <label>
    <div class="name">...</div>
    </label>
    <label>
    <div class="name">...</div>
    </label>
    <label>
    <div class="name">...</div>
    </label>
    <label>
    <div class="name">...</div>
    </label>
    <label>
    <div class="name">...</div>
    </label>
```

Lembrando que estas div's estão a ser escritas por uma função JavaScript (nesta função está a ser utilizado um `for`) com conteúdo diferente mas com a mesmas funcionalidades daí elas terem a mesma `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com jQuery você pode usar **[.wrap()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvJEk.png)**:

```
$(".name").wrap("<label />");
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu o meu problema ;)